# Stop vertical line from scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

We have a modal window (div) which is separated to two sections with a vertical border - `<div class="border"></div>` with the following CSS:

```
.modal-body {
    padding: 0px 15px;
}

.modal-body-left,
.modal-body-right {
    float: left;
    width: 381px;
    padding: 0px 0px 15px;
}

.border {
    border-left: 3px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    left: 396px;
}

.modal-body-right {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

The vertical line fits well into the parent div, but the problem is - if the parent div is very high and there is a vertical scroll bar, the vertical line scrolls with the scroll bar. How do we prevent it from scrolling (or change it's height to the full height of the parent div)? We don't want to put a border to the right or left sections, because they may not be the same height and we want the vertical border to cover the full height of its parent div.

Edit: this is the HTML (The contents are dynamic):

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="...">
    <div class="modal-header">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="post" id="...">
            <div class="modal-body-left">
                <h4>...</h4>
                <div class="line-div">
                    <label class="modal-label">...</label>
                    <div class="modal-div">...</div>
                </div>
                <div class="line-div">
                    <label class="modal-label">...</label>
                    <div class="modal-div">...</div>
                </div>
                <div class="line-div">
                    <label class="modal-label">...</label>
                    <div class="modal-div">...</div>
                </div>
                <div class="line-div">
                    <label class="modal-label">...</label>
                    <div class="modal-div">...</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="border"></div>
            <div class="modal-body-right">
                <h4>...</h4>
                <div class="line-div">
                    <label class="modal-label">...</label>
                    <div class="modal-div">...</div>
                </div>
                <div class="line-div">
                    <label class="modal-label">...</label>
                    <div class="modal-div">...</div>
                </div>
                <div class="line-div">
                    <label class="modal-label">...</label>
                    <div class="modal-div">...</div>
                </div>
                <div class="line-div">
                    <label class="modal-label">...</label>
                    <div class="modal-div">...</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: post your html too so that i can answer u in more detail..!!

Comment: @SajadLfc I posted my HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**CSS overflow**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property

```
.modal-body{
    height:300px;//your prefered value
    width:300px;//your prefered value    
    overflow:auto;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/35uTf/)

Comment: The parent div has to scroll if it's high. The border scrolls also with `overflow:hidden;`.

Comment: can you post the html or jsfiddle ??

Comment: It's already `overflow:auto;` and it doesn't change anything. The border still scrolls with its parent.

Comment: @Uri:you said you need the scroll for modal-body ??

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the vertical border scrolls too and it's not high enough.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in [CSS overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow).  For example, choosing the value: auto will only show the scrollbar when the content is too large.

Comment: We only need a scroll bar if the content is larger than the modal window.

Comment: @SajadLfc the scroll bar is for `<div class="modal-body">`.

Comment: @Uri:check my answer now then